# how to print more than one answer in prolog

Tags: prolog

the question is I have to print all the minimum starters, then the minimum main then the minimum dessert.
I wrote this

```
starter( greenSalad,10).
starter( seserSalad,20).
starter( tomatoSalad,10).
main( chicken,40).
main( pizza,30).
main( pasta,30).
dessert( raspberryCake,30).
dessert( fruitCake,20).
dessert( applepie,20).

min(Head,Tail,Head):- Head<Tail.
min(Head,Tail,Tail):- Tail<Head.
findmin([Only], Only).
findmin([Head|Tail], Minimum) :- findmin(Tail, TailMin), Minimum is
min(Head, TailMin).


**findMeal**2:-findall(Sp,starter(_,Sp),SList),findmin(SList,Spm),printStarter2(Spm),
    findall(Mp,main(_,Mp),MList),findmin(MList,Mpm),printMain2(Mpm),
    findall(Dp,dessert(_,Dp),DList),findmin(DList,Dpm),printDessert2(Dpm).


printStarter2(Spm):-starter(S,Spm),write(S),nl,fail.
printMain2(Mpm):-main(M,Mpm),write(M),nl,fail.
printDessert2(Dpm):-dessert(D,Dpm),write(D),nl,fail.
```

The PROBLEM is : this give all minimum starters, then stop without giving the minimum main and dessert

Answer (score 1):

Prolog tests predicates in order of their appearance in clause. It does nessesery unifications that would make the condition true. When it tries to prove findMeal, it proves findall/3, which always prove true, but does necessary unifications, ie. SList is bound after that.

Then it proves findmin/2, which unifies Spm with 10, and leaves choice point. It reaches printStarter2, and it tries to prove it, so it prints the greensaled and fails (fail/0, at the end of clause). It goes back to choice points and unifies Spm with 'next' 10 (from tomatoSalad). Inference engine goes yet again to printStarter, prints and fails again. As there are no more choice points, and last choice point failed, the predicate is unprovable, so inference engine stops and prints 'fail'.

If you want to fix that, make it print all the minimum meals, break the findMeal predicate into three clauses:

```
findMeal :- findall(Sp,starter(_,Sp),SList),findmin(SList,Spm),printStarter2(Spm).
findMeal :- findall(Mp,main(_,Mp),MList),findmin(MList,Mpm),printMain2(Mpm).
findMeal :- findall(Dp,dessert(_,Dp),DList),findmin(DList,Dpm),printDessert2(Dpm).
```

This will force the inference engine to create choice points right at the start of proving predicate. First predicate will fail after the same scenario as above, but inference engine will have more choice points - next findMeal clause, and so on.

Also, you might want to add one more findMeal clause, an empty one:

```
findMeal.
```

So the predicate will prove true after three previous clauses will fail.